# How to add custom message while refreshing crome browser

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Trying this code for alert message on refreshing the crome browser

```
@HostListener("window:beforeunload", ["$event"])
unloadHandler(event: Event) {
    let result = confirm("Changes 
    you made may not be saved.");
    if (result) {
      // Do more processing...
    }
    event.returnValue = false; // 
    stay on same page
}
```

Comment: you can check on this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-ve3mpy?file=app%2Fviews%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts